# What is the event for SAPUI5 SmartTable when loading data is failed?

Tags: sapui5

I need to run a code when the smart table cannot read the data from back-end. What kind of event I have to add to the smart table?

For example something like:

```
oSmartTable.getBinding("items").attachEventOnce("dataFailed", ....
```

We don't have such an event, but I need something like this.

Comment: Have you tried using the `dataReceived` event of the table `Binding` and checking whether `data` is undefined (if an error occurred, it should be undefined). You'll need to go via the table, i.e. `oSmartTable.getTable().getBinding().attachDataReceived(function(e) {// check e.getParameter('data')})`.

Comment: Yes data is not send there. I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a SmartTable with a table inside like this, we can use its `dataRequested` event:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable .....  dataRequested="onDataRequested">
  <m:Table id="table" ...>
  ....
  </m:Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

By using this event we try to add `dataReceived` event of the table:

```
onDataRequested: function(oEvent){
    var oTable =  this.byId("table");
    oTable.getBinding("items").attachEventOnce("dataReceived",function(oData) {
        if(!oData.getParameter("data")){
            // Do something here        
        }
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Please note that `dataRequested` of `SmartTable` is being deprecated. Using e.g. `oSmartTable.getTable().getBinding().attachDataReceived(function(e) {// check e.getParameter('data')})` will continue to work for longer...

Comment: yes, it has been said use  `beforeRebindTable` but I couldn't find out how to use it.   Also in the `beforeRebindTable` of the smarttable the `getBinding("items")` of the table is undefined. We have to bind the event to the enclosed table after data requested.

Comment: Why not use `oSmartTable.getTable().getBinding().attachDataReceived()`?

Comment: We must use `oSmartTable.getTable().getBinding("items")` and not `oSmartTable.getTable().getBinding()` as I used a table inside of the smart table. And the problem is both return `undefined` before the data is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution from UI5 1.56

In your view

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable" entitySet="PRs" smartFilterId="smartFilterBar"
 tableType="ResponsiveTable" beforeRebindTable=".onBeforeRebind">
```

In your Controller

```
onBeforeRebind: function (oEvent) {
  var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
  //Event handlers for the binding
  mBindingParams.events = {
    "dataReceived" : function(oEvent){
        var aReceivedData = oEvent.getParameter('data');
        },
        //More event handling can be done here
  };
}
```